# appWidgetManager won't update, and Christmas is almost here

Tags: android, textview, widget

I can't figure out why the appWidgetManager won't update in the bellow example. I am working on a similar widget project and need to update the textView from another method.

Almost two days of researching via Google, but no luck...Could someone light me up?

The Java part:

```
package com.example.napiige;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;


public class MainActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {

    int x;
    RemoteViews views;
    AppWidgetManager mgr;
    ComponentName myWidget2;

    @Override
     public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        task(context, mgr);

        }


     public void task(Context context, AppWidgetManager mgr) {

         this.mgr = mgr;
         myWidget2 = new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class);
         RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.example_appwidget);
         views2.setTextViewText(R.id.igePrint, "Hello"); 

         mgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
         mgr.updateAppWidget(myWidget2, views);


     }

}
```

UPDATE:

I have figured out. I was passing the wrong variable names through the "task()" method:

```
task(context, mgr);
```

had to be changed to:

```
task(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

Comment: put your manifest.xml file

Comment: have you written onReceive() method?

Comment: All I have in the java file is the onUpdate method as you can see in the example code above...do I need onReceive as well?? @Sharmilee

Comment: yes. post your whole java file

Comment: Updated the java code in the top example, this is all what is inside my java file @Sharmilee

Comment: Is this really that hard to figure out?